# Does not display printf result in cgo

Tags: c, go, cgo

When I ran this code, I expected to printing result like `A: 4, B: 89`.
But actually, Does not display nothing.

Why this program does not display result to stdout?

main.go:

```
package main

/*
#include "c.h"

*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
)

type S struct {
    A int
    B int
}

func main() {
    s := &S{A: 4, B: 89}
    pass_to_c := (*C.S)(unsafe.Pointer(s))
    C.gostruct(pass_to_c)
}
```

---

c.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    long int A;
    long int B;
} S;

extern void gostruct(S *struct_s) {
    printf("A: %ld, B: %ld\n", struct_s->A, struct_s->B);
}
```

Comment: The Go struct `S` and the C struct `S` are very likely not compatible on your system. You can't treat a pointer to one as a pointer to the other. Create an object of the type of the C structure instead — you can create and use a C structure from Go directly.

Comment: Use specific sized types, like `int64`, in a struct that needs to match a C struct. In this case use int64, or get the struct from the C definition. Since you can't access typedef structs through cgo, it's common to make a C wrapper to access them, rather than matching the struct manually in Go. That way you can let cgo generate them automatically, rather than manually checking the size and alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for comments.

I can got expected result with below codes

main.go:

```
package main

/*
#include "c.h"

*/
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
)

type S struct {
    A int64 // 64bit int
    B int64 // 64bit int 
}

func main() {
    s := &S{A: 4, B: 89}
    pass_to_c := (*C.S)(unsafe.Pointer(s))
    C.gostruct(pass_to_c)
}
```

c.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    long long int A; // 64bit int
    long long int B; // 64bit int
} S;

extern void gostruct(S *struct_s) {
    printf("{A: %lld, B: %lld}\n", struct_s->A, struct_s->B);
}
```

I suppose struct field must use same type between languages. 
In question code, struct fields type are not same. 
(C struct: 32bit int, Go struct: 64bit int)

In answer code, struct field is same between language.
(both struct: 64bit int)

*Note that My architecture is `darwin/amd64`*

Comment: This is still the wrong answer. It will fail on Windows. The correct answer is to create a `C.S` and use it directly; don't try to force a Go structure whose items will definitely be of a different size or alignment into a C structure.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `"console": "integratedTerminal"` to the vscode `launch.json` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I run program in LiteIDE, not show c printf output.

But run the same program in terminal,
then c printf output displayed.